# Repair or replace steering knuckle?

Tags: suspension, steering

I have a 2005 Chevrolet Suburban 1500 LS that needed new lower ball joints. I have had a very difficult time removing the steering knuckle from the ball joint. I tried penetrating lubricant, hitting it with a 3-lb sledge while jacking up the ball joint bolt, and even tried heating the knuckle. It is on there nice and tight.

I tried hitting different places on the knuckle, and in the process I hit the area above the hole where the bolt for the brake caliper bracket goes. I deformed the hole just enough that the bolt won't go through anymore. Is this something I can just drill out or have I compromised things enough that I should just buy a new steering knuckle?

[image: Lower Caliper Bracket Mounting Hole deformed]
[image: The bolt only goes this far]
In the second picture, you can see the caliper bracket mounting bolt only goes through until the threads hit at the very end. I don't think it would take much to drill it out to fit the bolt.

A new Dorman from Amazon is $105, and a used one from the local junkyard is $85.

Comment: How much would a new one cost?

Comment: Not a drill but use the proper metric Tap to rework the damaged threads. I would replace it, the caliper may not mount properly (flat and true) due to the distortion.

Comment: @Moab It's just a hole on the knuckle. The threads that the bolt connects with are on the brake caliper itself.

Comment: Oh, then you are correct, just drill it out.

Answer (score 1):

I would get a new or used knuckle to replace that one, I would not trust the damaged caliper mounting hole any more.

Comment: This is definitely the way I'm leaning as well.

Comment: Junkyard may be a good place to find a used one.

Comment: Especially considering that the used one might be just as hard to remove...

Answer (score 1):

With $20 difference to a new one, I'd go new. No hassle getting it off, or having a second-hand one delivered and finding it's covered in rust.

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely replace it with a new one.
There is no way of telling if there are no microscopic cracks / other damages weakening the area around the hole.
You also do not know what happened to the one from the junkyard during its lifetime.

I think that, in general, taking shortcuts on the suspension is too risky. Should the ball joint / steering knuckle / caliper bracket fail it would be a major disaster.

Bonus: The install of the new ball joint would be hassle-free.